# Why Redis get in async function is too slow?

Tags: node.js, redis, async-await

I have a code that looks like the following

```js
console.time('setfoo')
redis.set('foo', 'bar')

...

let result = await redis.get('foo')

console.timeEnd('setfoo')
```

Response time for this `get` is `263ms` but when I remove `await` it goes down to `0.037ms` What could be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `await` basically means "wait for this instruction to be completed before you do anything else".
Not using it would make your script execute quickly, but the `result` variable will only contain an unresolved Promise. [More on promises here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise)

In this case, redis does not use Promises natively, `await` is not needed.

What I don't get is your bit of code here:

```
let result = await redis.get(
  redis.get('foo')
)
```

You pass a call to redis as a parameter to another call to redis. Redis natively uses callbacks, so if you want to display the variable you got from redis, try:

```
let result = await redis.get('foo', (result) => { console.log(result) })
```

Also, since redis.set() is asynchronous, by the time you try to recover your data, `'foo'` might not have been set yet.

[This might help you use promises with redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#promises)

EDIT: Your code re-written according to the redis documentation

```js
const { promisify } = require("util");
const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(redis);
const setAsync = promisify(client.set).bind(redis);

...

console.time('setFoo')
await setAsync('foo', 'bar')

...

let result = await getAsync('foo', 'bar')
console.timeEnd('setfoo')
```

Comment: That was a mistake, corrected the code. Btw I use ioredis

Comment: Ok, I was way off then, disregard the bit about promisify. ioredis handles promises natively, so simply putting `await` before set() and get() should work.
As for the response time, is your redis server distant? This simply might be your network response time.

Comment: I don't network is the because my reply is fast without await. Am I missing something?

Comment: Without `await`, your code runs without waiting for redis to answer. Your redis server apparently takes 263ms to respond, this doesn't seem to be a code issue.

Comment: I don't understand that part. With or without await the Redis response time should be equal no? `timeEnd` should reflect that no?

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw my 2 cents here: V8 (the JavaScript engine behind browsers and NodeJS) is using an event-loop (powered by `libuv`) which does not necessarily execute tasks on a separate thread. What this event loop does is essentially accepting jobs and executing them when it can. More info on the event loop [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

With that being said, `.get` call adds a task to the event loop, which translates into a JavaScript `Promise` object. If you do not await that, the task is just added to the event loop. From your example:

```js
console.time('foo')
let result = redis.get('foo')
console.timeEnd('foo')
```

What you are actually measuring here is *how much time does it take for the event loop task to be submitted?*, which is insignificant.

Awaiting on the `.get` call will not only add the task to the event loop, but also block until the task executes:

```js
console.time('foo')
let result = await redis.get('foo')
console.timeEnd('foo')
```

So, to answer your question: the two times should not be equal at all, because one example is measuring how long it takes for Redis to process the request and return the result, while the other example is measuring just how long it takes for the job to be submitted to the event loop.